# Cos'è la "teoria del biscotto"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-origin

Un articolo apparso ieri in un giornale di Barcellona afferma che Valentino Rossi ha rispolverato la "teoria del biscotto" riferendosi a qualche sorta di manipolazione delle corse da parte di Marc Márquez e Jorge Lorenzo. C'è scritto proprio così, "teoria del biscotto", con la parola "biscotto" in italiano ("teoria" si scrive anche così in catalano). L'articolo però non spiega qual è il senso di questa espressione né perché si usa il termine "biscotto". La mie domande sono: il vocabolo "biscotto" ha qualche significato figurato che possa avere senso in questa situazione? Qual è l'origine di questo uso di "biscotto"? Ho cercato questa parola in alcuni dizionari, ma non ho trovato nulla al riguardo.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Biscotto* è un vero o presunto accordo nel campo sportivo per ottenere vantaggi, anche a discapito di qualche altro concorrente. Trovi [qui](http://www.ilpost.it/2012/06/18/ma-perche-si-dice-biscotto/) una possibile spiegazione.

Un famoso *biscotto* fu preparato agli Europei di calcio del 2004: con un pareggio, Svezia e Danimarca si sarebbero qualificate, mentre la vittoria di una o dell'altra avrebbe qualificato l'Italia; finì due a due.

Il più recente avvenne all'ultima gara di MotoGP dello scorso campionato, quando Marc Márquez avrebbe potuto attaccare Jorge Lorenzo e, con la vittoria, togliergli i punti che avrebbero dato il titolo a Valentino Rossi.

In entrambi i casi non ci sono prove che l'accordo ci sia stato, ma la “teoria del biscotto” (cioè la teoria del complotto) è molto diffusa.

Comment: Il problema principale del presunto "biscotto" fra Svezia e Danimarca nel 2004 era che non bastava un qualunque pareggio perche' si qualificassero entrambe: ci voleva un pareggio con almeno 2 goal. Senza questo requisito credo che la teoria del biscotto avrebbe avuto molto meno successo. Vale anche la pena di notare che in Italia hanno cominciato a parlare di biscotto non appena quel calcolo e' stato fatto, cioe' molto prima di quella partita. A quanto pare in Italia si dava per scontato che in una situazione del genere fosse automatico che le squadre agiscano in modo truffaldino.

Comment: @SantiBailors Avevo dimenticato il dettaglio, grazie per la precisazione. E giochiamo contro la Svezia domani!